# Not showing md-hint using email validator in Data-Driven forms

Tags: angular, data-driven, angular-forms

Im trying to display a md-hint when the email is not valid but it isnt displaying in my html.

**html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSignup()">
<md-input-container class="col-md-6 md-icon-left">
  <md-icon class="material-icons">mail_outline</md-icon>
  <input formControlName="email" mdInput #email type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
  <md-hint *ngIf="!email.pristine && email.errors != null && email.errors['noEmail']">Invalid mail address</md-hint>
</md-input-container>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```js
myForm: FormGroup;
error = false;
errorMessage = '';

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
            private authService: AuthService,
            rv: RutValidator) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    email: ['', Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            this.isEmail
        ])],
    });
}

isEmail(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if (!control.value.match(/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/)) {
        return {noEmail: true};
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `email` variable in your template is `HTMLInputElement` instance. You need to use FormControl instance to check errors like `myForm.get('email')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss insert `formGroup`.

you should write `[formGroup]='myForm'` at `<md-input-container class="col-md-6 md-icon-left">`.

And Augury chrome extention may help you and your form validation.

Answer (score 0):

It is just like @yurzui said,

> email variable in your template is HTMLInputElement instance. You need to use FormControl instance to check errors like myForm.get('email')

So you'd need to do this instead:

```
<md-hint *ngIf="!myForm.get('email').pristine && myForm.hasError('noEmail', 'email')">
  Invalid mail address
</md-hint>
```

If you are using Angular 4, you can use the built in Validator `email` and skip the custom validator altogether. Also `Validators.componse` is "old" Angular v 2 syntax. So you could do:

```
email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
```

and of course the corresponding error message in template:

```
myForm.hasError('email', 'email')
```